# WPF Binding second ListBox in relation to selected item in first ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'm new to WPF and MVVM ... i created a class WorkstationItem

```
public class WorkstationItem
{
    public WorkstationItem() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
    public List<UpdateItem> Updates { get; set; }
}
```

UpdateItem is another class:

```
public class UpdateItem
{
    public UpdateItem() { }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string KB { get; set; }
}
```

I create some dummy data:

```
private List<WorkstationItem> workstations = new List<WorkstationItem>();
workstations.Add(new WorkstationItem
{
    Name = "PC01",
    OS = "Windows Server 2019",
    Updates = new List<UpdateItem>{

    new UpdateItem { Title = "Test", KB = "KB123123" },
    new UpdateItem { Title = "Test2", KB = "KB123123" }
    }
});
workstations.Add(new WorkstationItem
{
    Name = "PC02",
    OS = "Windows Server 2016",
    Updates = new List<UpdateItem>{

    new UpdateItem { Title = "Test5", KB = "KB123123" },
    new UpdateItem { Title = "Test3", KB = "KB123123" }
    }
});
```

Now i show the workstations in a listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbPCs" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkstationItemList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OS}" FontSize="9" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<WorkstationItem> WorkstationItemList { get; set; }

WorkstationManager workstationmanager = WorkstationManager.GetInstance();
WorkstationItemList = new ObservableCollection<WorkstationItem>();

foreach (var k in workstationmanager.GetUpdatelist())
{
    WorkstationItemList.Add(k);
}
```

This is working fine ... but how can i show the `List<UpdateItem> Updates` in another list in relation to the selected workstation?

So i select a workstation in list1 and want to show the related updates in list2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically add another ListBox or ItemsControl that refers to SelectedItem of the existing ListBox and bind to the SelectedItem's `Updates` collection; roughly like (untested):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lbPCs, Path=SelectedItem.Updates}">
   <ListBox .ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate> 
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- TODO improve alignment+layout -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KB}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   <ListBox .ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In case you want to do something more complex with the selected item but to display its `Updates`, it might be more appropriate to bind the SelectedItem of lbPCs to some new ViewModel property and to bind the new ListBox' itemsource to that VM property's Updates collection.